# How to describe the face one makes when feeling sorry for someone?

Tags: phrase-requests

How to describe the face one makes - like pressing together of lips to form a straight line - when they feel sorry for a person but have no solution to offer? The kind of face that says, "sorry, mate. wish I could help." A phrase for it would also work.

Comment: "put up a 'sorry-ass' face"

Answer (score 3):

I would use **[commiserative](https://www.wordnik.com/words/commiserative)**.

> Feeling or expressing commiseration, compassion, pity or sympathy

–from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License; via Wordnik

Answer (score 2):

The first word that came to my mind was a "sympathetic" face.

> **sympathetic (to/towards somebody)** kind to somebody who is hurt or sad; showing that you understand and care about their problems

–[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sympathetic?q=sympathetic)

Some actual examples from Google Books of this phrase being used:

> His sympathetic face said she had a shoulder to cry on should she wish

– [*For Want of a Fiend*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CjOUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=%22sympathetic%20face%22&source=bl&ots=PYpTLMl0P1&sig=z5lEcBgKAMLuXFlJDOLpkHx-3ZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7gfOo0qTKAhXHRyYKHfd7D0Y4FBDoAQg_MAg#v=onepage&q=%22sympathetic%20face%22&f=false), by Barbara Ann Wright

> Suyana couldn't hear Grace's response, but Ethan made a pained, sympathetic face.

– [*Persona*](https://books.google.com/books?id=X4zeAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22sympathetic%20face%22&source=bl&ots=us2bKcjVNB&sig=_20j-Ae-mqLMWWBQklpLR-Kf1pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7gfOo0qTKAhXHRyYKHfd7D0Y4FBDoAQg8MAc#v=onepage&q=%22sympathetic%20face%22&f=false), by Genevieve Valentine

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [**apologetic**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apologetic) which means the following:

> Expressing or showing regretful acknowledgement of an offence or
>   failure: '*an apologetic smile*'

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> Ha made an apologetic face that said, "Sorry, mate. wish I could
>   help."

Answer (score 0):

Consider **Compassionate**.

> Definition: pitying, sympathizing, showing a feeling of deep sympathy
> and sorrow for another who is stricken by misfortune, accompanied by a
> strong desire to alleviate the suffering.

Example from [*Can you tell the difference between a smiling and
menacing face?*](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2572231/Can-tell-difference-smiling-menacing-face-Abuse-victims-game-rewire-brain.html):

> Participants search for a *compassionate face* among a number of
> critical faces, which retrains the automatic, unconscious biases
> towards threatening stimuli commonly shown by people with mood
> disorders, according to the study published in Plos One journal.

Comment: "sorry, mate. wish I could help" isn't terribly compassionate.